# Matlab: Solve Symbolic Equation with Exponent

Tags: matlab

Cosider the following code

```
syms x u a l
H = (x*u)^a - l*u;
d = solve(diff(H, u) == 0, u)
```

This is a FOC and `d` a maximizer. Now the maximizer is unique and given by `d=(l/(a*x))^(1-a)/x`. However, Matlab struggels with solving for `d`. It says

```
Warning: The solutions are parameterized by the symbols: k.
 To include parameters and conditions in the solution, specify the 'ReturnConditions' option. 
> In solve>warnIfParams (line 500)
  In solve (line 356) 
Warning: The solutions are valid under the following conditions: ((pi/2 + angle(l/(a*x))/(2*(a - 1)))*(a - 1))/pi < k & k <= -((pi/2 - angle(l/(a*x))/(2*(a -
1)))*(a - 1))/pi & in(k, 'integer').
 To include parameters and conditions in the solution, specify the 'ReturnConditions' option. 
> In solve>warnIfParams (line 507)
  In solve (line 356) 

d =

(exp(-(pi*k*2i)/(a - 1))*(l/(a*x))^(1/(a - 1)))/x
```

- Why is that and how can I get the right solution symbolically?

Comment: Is there any evidence to believe the solution is wrong?

Comment: I just know that the analytical solution is different. Or at least I know how to derive an easier solution. The derivative of H is `dH/du = a(x*u)^(a-1) - l`. Set it equal to zero and solve for `u`, which yields  `dH/du = 0 <=> u = (l/(a*x))^(1-a)/x`.

Comment: @clueless the derivative is `a*x*(u*x)^(a - 1) - l`, you can check it by doing `diff(H,u)`

Comment: There was something wrong in my comment. `dH/du = a*x*(x*u)^(a-1) - l` and the maximizer is  `u = (l/(a*x))^(1/(1-a))/x`. @AnderBiguri: the derivatve is not the problem, but to solve for  `u`.

Comment: Have you tried specifying `assumptions` on any of your variables?

Comment: Also Matlab's solution matches your fixed solution in your comment if `k` is set to zero. Exponential equations can have an invite number of complex-valued solutions – try `d = solve(diff(H, u) == 0, u,'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints',true)`.

Comment: Thanks, this works.